# LaTex cases Howto?

Tags: cases

beginner here (downloaded LaTex today) so please be kind.
I am trying to get 'cases' to work, but it doesn't seem to understand "&" to separate the equation from the description, nor "\ \" to split the rows.
I'm thinking I need to download something extra for these to work?
Otherwise I get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$$
1/S=\begin{cases}
1/P-1/P_{\oplus} & inferior \\ 
1/P_{\oplus }-1/P & superior 
\end{cases}
$$
\end{document}
```

resulting in: "Misplaced alignment tab character &."

Without the '&'s I get the two equations on one row instead of separated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: load the amsmath package.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: \usepackage{amsmath}

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @Pep Not use $$ double dollar!! See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to#:~:text=LaTeX%20doesn't%20officially%20support,than%20being%20set%20flush%20left.

Answer (score 5):

Load the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
1/S=\begin{cases}
1/P-1/P_{\oplus} & \text{inferior} \\
1/P_{\oplus }-1/P & \text{superior} 
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]